# writing to a tcp socket

Tags: sockets, tcp

This is a pretty elementary question. I'm just starting some socket programming and I am using qt/c++. I wrote a trivial program as an exercise which connects to a socket (the localhost loopback at port 80), writes some data to it, waits for repsonse, and then outputs the response in my terminal.

Here's the main method of the program:

```
void TcpSocket::ConnectSocket()
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost("localhost", 80);

    if(socket->waitForConnected(3000)){
        qDebug() << "Connected";

        socket->write("Hello Server");
        socket->waitForBytesWritten(1000);
        socket->waitForReadyRead(3000);
        qDebug() << "Reading: " << socket->bytesAvailable();
        qDebug() << socket->readAll();
        socket->close();
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Could not connect";
    }
}
```

The response of the code above is this:

```
Connected 
Reading:  0 
""
```

Now, right now I actually have a virtual host set up for localhost at port 80 that serves a web page on my local machine. When I execute that program, absolutely nothing appears to happen at the endpoint localhost:80.

If port 80 is listening, where does it write "Hello Server" to? And why doesn't it respond?

Answer (score 0):

The web server did not respond to what you wrote because you did not finish sending a request. At minimum, you'll need to add "\n\r\n" to your write.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: Another problem is I am having to create a server on one of my ports within ubuntu itself:  sudo nc -l 77. Is there a way to do tell the operating system to create a network connection on a specified port within my qt program?

Comment: Of course, anything is possible.  In general, it's bad security to run things as root. Just use high port numbers (above 1024) instead.